# How do I enforce a parameter in a blazor component?

Tags: blazor

```
<MyComponent MyParameter="@MyParameter"></MyComponent>
```

I want the ***MyComponent*** tag to throw an error when no value is supplied to ***MyParameter*** parameter.

Comment: Do a null check on it in `ParametersSet` or `OnInitialized` event override `MyComponent` code section, then throw the error if it's null.

Comment: Look, .Net's EditForm component throws an error when Model parameter is not supplied, that's the kind of error I'd love to have. `<EditForm ></EditForm>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MrC aka Shaun Curtis's answer gets the job done at runtime, but if you want you can go further and use the `EditorRequired` annotation on your parameter. This will create warnings at design-time if the parameter is not set.

```
[Parameter]
[EditorRequired]
public string MyParameter { get; set; }
```

Requires .NET 6, read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-6/#required-blazor-component-parameters).

This does not throw errors at runtime however, so you still need to check the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Both the other answers are valid, but I would do this:

```
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (MyParameter == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MyComponent)} requires a {nameof(MyParameter)} parameter.");

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
```

Why?  `SetParametersAsync` is the entry method called by the Renderer on the component: no component code has been run.  If, say you put your checking in `OnParametersSet{Async}`, you may have tried to use it in `OnInitialized{Async}` - you haven't told us why it must be set!